# SQLite no registra filas en aplicación para Windows Phone 8.1 usando patrón MVVM, C#

Tags: c#, xaml, sqlite, binding, mvvm

Me encuentro desarrollando una aplicación para Windows Phone 8.1, es una aplicación simple para una tienda. Estoy usando el patrón de diseño MVVM, y utilizo SQLite para el almacenamiento. Cuando trato de insertar algunas filas para realizar las pruebas, la aplicación se salta el proceso de InsertOrUpdate y no las añade.

Aquí está mi código en XAML, Desde donde llamo a mi VistaModelo:

```
<ListBox Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Grid.Row="2"
         Margin="15,0" ItemsSource="{Binding Products}"
         Background="Black" 
         ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
```

Llamando al comando de creación de la base de datos desde CodeBehind:

```
public ListProducts()
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    ListProductsVM ListProductsOnView = new ListProductsVM();
    if (ListProductsOnView.CreateCommand.CanExecute(null))
    ListProductsOnView.CreateCommand.Execute(null);
}
```

Mi ICommand CreateCommand, y la lista de productos:

```
public ICommand CreateCommand
{
    get { return this._createCommand; }
}
public ObservableCollection<ProductsVM> Products
{
    get { return this.products; }
    set { this.SetProperty(ref this.products, value); }
}
private async void Create_Executed()
{
    await DAL.CreateDatabase();
}
```

Y con esto debería crear la base de datos con tres filas:

```
public static async Task CreateDatabase()
{
    var result = await Checkdatabase();
    if (!result)
    {
        // Create a new connection
        using (var db = DbConnection)
        {
            // Active tracing
            db.TraceListener = new DebugTraceListener();

            // Create the tables if they does not exist
            var prod = db.CreateTable<Product>();
            var sale = db.CreateTable<Sales>();
            var kard = db.CreateTable<Kardex>();
            var infoprod = db.GetMapping(typeof(Product));
            var infosale = db.GetMapping(typeof(Sales));
            var infokard = db.GetMapping(typeof(Kardex));

        // TODO Delete this values
            Product product = new Product();
            product.ID = 1;
            product.Name = "Galletas";
            product.Unit = "Unidad";
            product.Cost = 12.00;
            product.Price = 15.00;
            product.Active = true;

            var i = db.InsertOrReplace(product);

            product = new Product();
            product.ID = 2;
            product.Name = "Leche";
            product.Unit = "Litros";
            product.Cost = 8.00;
            product.Price = 10.00;
            product.Active = false;

            i = db.InsertOrReplace(product);

            product = new Product();
            product.ID = 3;
            product.Name = "Orégano";
            product.Unit = "Unidad";
            product.Cost = 0.20;
            product.Price = 0.30;
            product.Active = true;

            i = db.InsertOrReplace(product);
        }
    }

}
```

Debería añadir los tres productos, pero no lo hace.

Alguna idea de qué es lo que podría estar ocasionándolo? Agradezco de antemano a todos los que me apoyen.

[ACTUALIZACIÓN]
Esto es lo que aparece en el Output:

```
Executing: insert OR REPLACE into "Product"("ID","Name","Unit","Cost","Price","Active") values (?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

Tengo otro proyecto similar en el que obtengo los mismos resultados, pero en ese sí se registran los elementos y se mandan al modelo, el procedimiento que estoy siguiendo es el mismo.

Comment: cuando el registro salta el InsertOrUpdate quiere decir que hay un error no controlado, define un bloque try..catch que abarque la operacion de insert y veras como obtienes una exception que analizar

Comment: Gracias @LeandroTuttini
He añadido el try...catch, pero no ingresa al catch, por lo que me parece que sí se ejecuta el comando, pero cuando analizo el código paso por paso no llega a insertar la fila.

Comment: pero entonces porque mencionaste que se salta el proceso ? si en realidad esta llegando y ejecutando el InsertOrUpdate()

Comment: que libreria estas usando para trabjar con SQLite ? porque analizando Linq to Sql no veo que tenga ninguna InsertOrUpdate() sera que usa esta extension https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/5d97faf6-39e3-4048-a0bc-adde2af75d1b

Comment: @LeandroTuttini lo digo porque no llegan a insertarse las filas, tengo otro proyecto en el que cada vez que se ejecuta ese comando, el modelo Product también toma los valores, y las filas se añaden sin problemas. En este proyecto no es el caso.

Comment: @LeandroTuttini
Sí, estoy utilizando esa extensión. Por qué lo mencionas? Gracias por el seguimiento.

Comment: puede ser que el repositorio lo hayas ubicado en el storage que no tiene acceso de escritura, que pasa si lo cambias de ubicacion? Esto sucede cuando ejecutas desde el VS o desde el dispositivo ?

Comment: @LeandroTuttini lo ejecuto desde VS, utilizo un emulador de WP8.1. Cuando dices cambiar de ubicación, te refieres a establecer otro Path?

Answer (score 0):

Recuerda que el Win Phone no tienes acceso a cualquier carpeta, por eso es que se usan las clases de `Storage` para acceder al ambito donde la aplicacion tiene acceso.

[Quickstart: Working with files and folders in Windows Phone 8](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/jj681698(v=vs.105).aspx)

Deberias validar donde esta ubicada esa carpeta

```
StorageFolder local = Windows.Storage.ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder;
```

y colocar alli el archivo de la db.

Como veras no puedes poner el archivo en cualquier sitio, ya que la aplicacion esta limitada donde puede o no acceder.

Nota: usa esta carpeta en el connection string para referenciar la db.

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero lamento decir que ese no es el problema, he realizado la asignación que indicas en otro método previamente, el problema no se encuentra en la conexión, ya que en efecto crea las tablas (en el output indica la creación de las tablas).
Como dije anteriormente, el problema radica en que se salta InsertOrReplace.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que estás trabajando con esta librería. En ese caso debes asegurarte de algunas cosas:
1. En la clase **Product** debes definir una **PK** (**Primary Key**). Lo definimos como Nullable para que cada vez que se utiliza el método **InsertOrReplace** con **ID = 0** no reemplace un fila existente:

```
[PrimaryKey]
public Nullable<int> ID { get; set; }
```

2. Estoy de acuerdo con Leandro, en el sentido de tu **Path**. Estás teniendo un problema de escritura en la carpeta donde está ubicado tu archivo **.db**